# Cant save an excel file using python script

Tags: python, openpyxl, qfiledialog

```
def getFile():
    global filename, path, path2

    filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
    path = filename

    print(path)
```

I think the problem is in this function

```
def getTo():
    wb = load_workbook(filename = filename)
```

and there is mising some settings in filename functon,
i tried using unicode, but it doesnt solve the problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pro10/PycharmProjects/Program/gui5.py", line 118, in getTo
    sheet['A' + str(rows)] = text1
  File "C:\Users\pro10\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 313, in __setitem__
    self[key].value = value
  File "C:\Users\pro10\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 216, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\pro10\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 199, in _bind_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert <function text1 at 0x0000023DFE3D3A60> to Excel
```

Comment: what error are you getting.I mean in terminal

Comment: Please [edit] describe the expected behavior and the actual behavior, and if there are errors, also post the full error (starts with Traceback). It's currently not clear what problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the `load_workbook` function, like this?

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

Comment: @АлексейОрлов please provide the full Traceback. And what libraries are you using?